# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a form and import submitted data to a database,

```
<?php
// db has to be manually created first
$host = "localhost";
$userName = "user";
$password = "";
$dbName = "test";

// Create database connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $userName, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


if((isset($_POST['your_name'])&& $_POST['your_name'] !='') && (isset($_POST['your_email'])&& $_POST['your_email'] !=''))
{

$yourName = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['your_name']);
$yourEmail = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['your_email']);
$yourPhone = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['your_phone']);
$comments = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_form_info (name, email, phone, comments)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)";



//$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
//if ($stmt = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO contact_form_info WHERE name = ?  email = ? phone = ? comments = ? ")) {
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $yourName, $yourEmail, $yourPhone,$comments);

$stmt->execute();
}
```

When I submit my form, I get the following error

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?)"

Can someone please check my code and tell me what's wrong with it?

And thanks in advance

Comment: Did you do what the error message told you to do?

Comment: If you are using bound parameterised statement like you are the escape nonsense is irrelevant and not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error shows that for some reason, the question marks are not being bound to the appropriate variables. MySQL is complaining because the question marks are not encapsulated with `""`.

Ass @RiggsFolly pointed out, you don't need to call `$conn->real_escape_string` as you are using prepared statements.

(Also, there is no need to check `isset()` and an empty string, `empty()` basically does an `isset` anyway)

```
<?php
// db has to be manually created first
$host = "localhost";
$userName = "user";
$password = "";
$dbName = "test";

// Create database connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $userName, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(!empty($_POST['your_name']) && !empty($_POST['your_email']) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO contact_form_info (name, email, phone, comments) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['your_name'], $_POST['your_email'], $_POST['your_phone'],$_POST['comments']);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```